# Avoiding Matlab's underflow prevention in backprop, due to performance cost

Tags: neural-networks, matlab, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent, underflow

In Matlab, I understand that if a number gets closer to zero than `realmin`, then Matlab converts the double to a [denorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) . I am noticing this causes significant performance cost. In particular I am using a gradient descent algorithm that when near convergence, the gradients (of my bespoke neural network) drop below `realmin` such that the algorithm incurs heavy performance cost (due to, I am assuming, type conversion behind the scenes). I have used the following code to validate my gradient matrices so that no numbers falls below `realmin`:

`function mat= validateSmallDoubles(obj, mat, threshold)
            mat= mat.*(abs(mat)>threshold);
 end`

Is this usual practice and what value should `threshold` take (obviously you want this as close to `realmin` as possible, but not too close otherwise any additional division operations will send some elements of `mat` below `realmin` *after* validation)?. Also, specifically for neural networks, where are the best places to do gradient validation without ruining the network's ability to learn?. I would be grateful to know what solutions people with experience in training neural networks have? I am sure this is a problem for all languages. Tentative `threshold` values have ruined my network's learning.

Comment: This is the same question on stack overflow: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425657/matlab-dealing-with-denorm-performance-cost-conversion-when-close-to-realmin-fo

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the diminishing gradient occurrences to the Adam SGD optimiser - the biased moving average matrix calculations in the Adam optimiser were causing matlab to carry out the denorm operation. I simply thresholded the matrix elements for each layer after these calculations, with `threshold=10*realmin`, to zero without any effect on learning. I have yet to investigate why my moving averages were getting so close to zero as my architecture and weight initialisation priors would normally mitigate this.